# ssh clone not working with github, what might be the issue?

Tags: git, ubuntu, github, ssh

I have generated ssh key-pair for my account and added public key to my both bitbucket and github account. I am able to clone successfully from our org's bitbucket but unable to clone our org's github repo using SSH.

Following are the results

```
git clone git@github.com:xxx/abc.git
Cloning into 'abc'...
ssh: connect to host github.com port 22: Connection timed out
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

Tried following command but it gets stuck at connecting

```
ssh -vT git@github.com
OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.5, OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/*.conf matched no files
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to github.com [20.207.73.82] port 22.
debug1: connect to address 20.207.73.82 port 22: Connection timed out
ssh: connect to host github.com port 22: Connection timed out
```

But the following command works

```
ssh -vT -p 443 git@ssh.github.com
OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.5, OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/*.conf matched no files
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to ssh.github.com [20.207.73.83] port 443.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/myuser/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/myuser/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/myuser/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/myuser/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/myuser/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/myuser/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/myuser/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /home/myuser/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/myuser/.ssh/id_ed25519 type 3
debug1: identity file /home/myuser/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/myuser/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /home/myuser/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/myuser/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file /home/myuser/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.5
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version babeld-6046b64f
debug1: no match: babeld-6046b64f
debug1: Authenticating to ssh.github.com:443 as 'git'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:p2QAMXNIC1TJYWeIOttrVc98/R1BUFWu3/LiyKgUfQM
debug1: checking without port identifier
The authenticity of host '[ssh.github.com]:443 ([20.207.73.83]:443)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:p2QAMXNIC1TJYWeIOttrVc98/R1BUFWu3/LiyKgUfQM.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no/[fingerprint])? yes
Warning: Permanently added '[ssh.github.com]:443,[20.207.73.83]:443' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/myuser/.ssh/id_ed25519 ED25519 SHA256:jQIcEmfKxygZTBMM2W22ia6pPFigVGBLUIqcFGSlxy4 agent
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/myuser/.ssh/id_rsa 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/myuser/.ssh/id_dsa 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/myuser/.ssh/id_ecdsa 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/myuser/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/myuser/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/myuser/.ssh/id_xmss 
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /home/myuser/.ssh/id_ed25519 ED25519 SHA256:jQIcEmfKxygZTB112W22ia6pPFigVGBLUIqcFGSlxy4 agent
debug1: Server accepts key: /home/myuser/.ssh/id_ed25519 ED25519 SHA256:jQIcEmfKxygZTB112W22ia6pPFigVGBLUIqcFGSlxy4 agent
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to ssh.github.com ([20.207.73.83]:443).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com want_reply 0
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_IN
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
Hi my-github-username! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
Transferred: sent 2156, received 2552 bytes, in 0.4 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 5121.8, received 6062.6
debug1: Exit status 1
```

I dont know what to make of it or how to solve this issue, I have tried generating another key-pair and adding it but it still doesn't work. We are also using org's Open VPN, if that matters

Comment: Possible reasons could be you dont have access to repository or no internet. May be your machine is disallowed to access git. You could generate a personal access token and try again follow this link https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something, either on your network or on an ISP between you and GitHub, is blocking your attempt to connect to github.com port 22. That verbose SSH output is the telltale sign: normally you'd establish a TCP connection first, and then get to the key exchange, but instead you get "Connection timed out". (Your keys are fine - otherwise you wouldn't have gotten your username back on that `ssh -Tvp443 git@ssh.github.com` command.)

https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/troubleshooting-ssh/using-ssh-over-the-https-port details a pretty slick workaround: using `~/.ssh/config` to define `github.com` with the SSH-specific hostname and port, so that the usual `git@github.com` works every time (even though you're actually being sneaky about host and port).

Alternately, you clone each repository with a special syntax, `ssh://git@ssh.github.com:443/xxx/abc.git`, and let the remote take care of the details.

Comment: Thanks JIm, adding in the config file helped, alternatively using special syntax also worked but that is a bit tedious!